# invalid operands to binary expression when push element in a priority queue

Tags: c++, c++11, priority-queue, std

I'm new in c++ programming. I've to create a priority queue of a Class named Container. So I've written this way:

**In main.cpp:**

```
struct Comp{
    bool operator() (const Container& a, const Container& b){
        return a<b;
    }
};

std::priority_queue<Container, std::list<Container>, Comp> containers;
```

**In Container.cpp:**

```
class Container{
public:
    friend bool operator< (const Container& a, const Container& b);
    //...
};

bool operator<(const Container &a, const Container &b) {
    return a.y<b.y;
}
```

I don't know why, even if I've declared a < operator overload, it gives me the same error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::__list_iterator<Container, void *>' and 'std::__1::__list_iterator<Container, void *>')
    __sift_up<_Comp_ref>(__first, __last, __comp, __last - __first);
```

How can I resolve this ? I don't really know what's going on :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's telling you that your it can't calculate the difference between two iterators of type `list<Container>::interator`.

If you look at the requirements for `priority_queue` on [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) it says that the iterators for the container "must satisfy the requirements of LegacyRandomAccessIterator."

`list`s iterators are not random-access; they are bidirectional. Therefore, you can't use a `list` as the underlying container for a `priority_queue`.

Simple fix: Use a `deque` instead of a `list`.

`std::priority_queue<Container, std::deque<Container>, Comp> containers;`